# Django tables names

Tags: python, django, django-models, refactoring

I am refactoring a Django application. Specifically, I have an application with a big `models.py` file and I am trying to split it into a bunch of small files, like

```
myapp/
    models/
        __init__.py
        somemodels.py
        someothers.py
        somemore.py
        ...
```

and in `models/__init__.py` I import all models from all other files so that I do not have to change client code.

The problem is that Django now complains about table names. Table for model `Foo` used to be `myapp_foo`, but it seems that Django now looks for a table `myapp.models_foo`. That is, it seems that it uses as prefix the package where the models are defined instead of their application (of course `myapp.models` is not registered as a Django application).

> I know I could manually set the table name for each and every models, but is there a way to avoid this and tell Django that these models are actually part of `myapp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Meta.app_label`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#app-label)